# GitLab not showing difference in branches after reverting merge commit

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-diff

I have two branches, `master` and `dev`, I merged `dev` into `master` without a merge request on GitLab.

**Problem:**
Now if I try to raise merge request on GitLab from `dev` to `master`, it shows no difference.

**Solution tried:**
I created one more branch from `master` and reverted the merge commit from that branch using

> git revert -m

after doing this when I try to raise merge request on GitLab it still says

> There isn't anything to merge.

But I can see the difference when I try to compare the branches locally.

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a LifeHack:

1. You do a merge of branch "Task" to the master
2. Something goes wrong and you press the "revert" button and GitLab makes a new branch with name something like "revert-1" and a merge request for it
3. You merge branch "revert-1" to the master
4. Then you make some changes to your branch "Task" and there are no changes when you try to merge it to the master (Oops...)
5. So you seek for that merge request of branch "revert-1" and press the "revert" button for it - GitLab makes new branch "revert-2" with reverted changes of "revert-1"
6. Merge "revert-2" into your "Task"
7. Then merge your "Task" to the master
8. Congratulations! You're awesome!

Comment: That worked like charm. Thanks.

Comment: bro you are such a legend. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Well, yes, because it's already merged. If you look at the network tab in gitlab or git log you will see the revert is after the merge. Revert does not rewrite the history, it adds a new commit.

Instead of doing a revert use `git reset --hard <commit>` to reset the master branch to state before the merge and then `git push -f`.

Comment: Your now-traditional warning that it is a *very bad idea* to force push to a remote repo that is also used by anybody else.

Comment: yeah i pushed to `main` and there's no way in hell I want to do `push -f` onto main to fix the issue